# When calculating two strings it return in TextView as nullnull

Tags: java, android

Sorry this is my first time newbie in android development. I'm doing a calculator So for example adding this numbers with any of the operator it always

The range of numbers is 0-1, I pick "1" and "2" since the buttons have the same java code

**Code**

```
public void btn1_click (View v) {

    String currentTextData = tvresult.getText().toString();
    currentTextData = currentTextData + "1";
    tvresult.setText(currentTextData);
}
public void btn2_click (View v){

    String currentTextData = tvresult.getText().toString();
    currentTextData = currentTextData + "2";
    tvresult.setText(currentTextData);
}

public void btnAdd_click (View v){
    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mlastClickTime < 1000){
        return;
    }
    mlastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    String val1 = tvresult.getText().toString();
    val1 = val1 + "+";
    add = true;
    tvresult.setText(val1);

}
public void btnSub_click (View v){
    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mlastClickTime <1000){
        return;
    }
    mlastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    String val1 = tvresult.getText().toString();
    val1 = val1 + "-";
    sub = true;
    tvresult.setText(val1);
}


public void btnEqual_click(View v) {
    if (add) {
        val1 += val2;
        tvresult.setText(val1);
    }


}
```

My.xml

```
 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/tvresult"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="155dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:maxLength="18"
     android:maxLines="1"
     android:textAlignment="center"
     android:gravity="bottom"
     android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
     android:textSize="40sp"
     android:visibility="visible"/>

<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="80dp"
     android:onClick="btn1_click"
     android:text="1"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
     android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:onClick="btn2_click"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button1" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/plus1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:onClick="btnAdd_click"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button3"/>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/equals1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:onClick="btnEqual_click"
    android:text="="
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/clear1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/clear1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/clear1" />
```

Comment: and What is your expectation?, what should happen when you add 2 String with `+` operator

Comment: Do I need to convert the strings into integer?

Answer (score 2):

You need to typecast string to int like..

Integer.parseINt(number_string);

and you have to typecast int value before setting as text in textView like..

Stirng.valueOf(int_value)

Answer (score 1):

Only integer values can perform calculation operation.
So you first have to change your string value to integer and then need to add some value in it.

```
String result = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(tvresult.getText().toString()) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit text is empty. Check if value is null or empty using `android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty`

**Please find the updated code below:**

```
 public void btn1_click (View v) {
    String currentTextData = tvresult.getText().toString();
    if(android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(currentTextData)) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter value 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
          int value = 0;
          try {
             value = Integer.parseInt(currentTextData);
          } catch(Exception e) {}
          value = value + 1;
          String updatedValue = String.valueOf(value);
          tvresult.setText(updatedValue);
    }

}

public void btn2_click (View v){
    String currentTextData = tvresult.getText().toString();
    if(android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(currentTextData)) {
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter value 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
          int value = 0;
          try {
             value = Integer.parseInt(currentTextData);
          } catch(Exception e) {}
          value = value + 2;
          String updatedValue = String.valueOf(value);
          tvresult.setText(updatedValue);
    }
}

public void btnAdd_click (View v){
    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mlastClickTime < 1000){
        return;
    }
    mlastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    String val1 = tvresult.getText().toString();
    val1 = val1 + "+";
    add = true;
    tvresult.setText(val1);

}

public void btnEqual_click(View v) {
    if (add) {
        val1 += val2;
        tvresult.setText(val1);
    }
}
```

**Do not add "1" to String if you want to increment it.**

Comment: 'String.value(value)' before the bracket "value" it could not resolve it

Comment: Updated answer. Use String.valueOf

Comment: But it returns as "nullnullnull" I'm doing a calculator I do not need toast

Comment: Then you are getting value from some other edit text or text view. Please post complete code

Comment: Including layout and activity

Comment: Edited already some of the code are repetitive so I cut some of the numbers